# How can I open a .gz.td file?

Tags: extract, ibm, decompression

I have a file named [IBM Quickstart Linux.gz.td](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=swg-beta-iibob&S_PKG=dl&lang=en_US&cp=UTF-8&dlmethod=http), which I am having trouble extracting. Archive Manager says that it is not supported. How do I extract `.gz.td` files in Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: Can you link that file ? The only .td files i can find are for DOS

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `file "IBM Quickstart Linux.gz.td"`

Comment: where did you get this file?

Comment: Question is edited, u can check. @Ron

Comment: couldn't see any file with the name you've given. In addition, I could only see `tar.gz` files.

Comment: Can you answer [A.B.'s comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/655613/how-can-i-open-a-gz-td-file#comment942759_655613) ?

Comment: It would be of big help, if you could tell us what a `.gz.td` file is. Is there any publicly available specification for its format (say, like POSIX is for `.tar`)? Is there any well-known canonical application that produces it (say, like MS Word is for `.doc`)?

Comment: Nothing on this site, see your link, is a `.gz.td`. See my screenshot http://i.imgur.com/lNDWXEH.png

Comment: @A.B. did you see any `gz.td`? There are only `tar.gz` and `7z`

Comment: @Ron Not `gz.td`. Only well known formats.

Comment: I have downloaded 2nd file (tar.gz) but when downloaded it is showing .gz.td  format. I was also amazed by having a sight before providing link here. I tried converting it into tar.gz format But it doesn't work. It's approx. 3.4 GB file.

Comment: The only references I can find suggest it's an incomplete download file produced by Thunder (Xunlei?)  - a Chinese localized download manager?

Comment: How you came to know that file is downloaded by "Thunder(Xunlei)-a chinese localized download manager ?"  coz i have downloaded it from UC Browser ? Can you please give an answer or explain @steeldriver

Answer (score 2):

1. Open terminal by tapping
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. In terminal type command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
   ```

   press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. After that in terminal type

   ```
   7z x /path/to/your/file
   ```

   press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**I have not tried this, but with 7zip I extract different types of archives, which are not available on Archive Manager.**

Comment: Doen't work .   "Error: there is no such archive"

Comment: Change file name, remove spaces, change filename to IBM.gz.td

Comment: Still gives the same error.

Comment: @Aevi send me your file on zviadgabroshvili@gmail.com or on facebook  find me http://facebook.com/zviadi.gabroshvili.8